# MaterializeCSS how to make select input green(valid) on onleave()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, materialize

We are developing a web app and we are using NET CORE, materializeCSS. In the form we have only 2 inputs, textbox and select(dropdown).

This is the scenario/step I did,

1. Submit the form(while having textbox and select no value)
2. Input and textbox's bottom border become red,
3. I choose a value in select,
4. Click textbox,
5. The redline bottom-border in select does not become green(which is it suppose to be because the select has now a value)

But in textbox it complete works just how it should be. I know this is a minor error and the form still can submit even when the select is in redline. But it still an bug in UI specially on the users.

Please help thanks.

CSHTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s8 offset-s2">
        <select asp-for="Type" class="validate" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<FieldType>()" required>
            <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        </select>
        <label for="Type">Type<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    initAjaxForm("#f_addfield", "validate");
});
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.